# CURL with @ in username

Tags: php, curl

I trying to upload a file with CURL by FTP. but I have a problem with the username, in my hosting all the FTP usernames  are user@site.com so I get the following error when I try to upload:

Curl error: Couldn't resolve host 'site.com:password@site.com'

Here is the code:

```
      $ftpuser = 'uploader@mysite.com';
      $ftppass = "blablabla";
      $ftppath = "mysite.com/";
      $ftpurl = "ftp://".$ftpuser.":".$ftppass."@".$ftppath;
```

can someone tell me how can I pass the username to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. You should be able to get around the `@` problem by using [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to convert the non-safe character.
2. It would be better to use the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option with `curl_setopt` to set the username and password pair, I believe.

So:

```
<?php 

$ftpuser = urlencode('uploader@mysite.com');
$ftppass = urlencode('blablabla');
$ftppath = 'mysite.com/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://' . $ftppath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ftpuser . ':' . $ftppass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

can you give curl the username and password seperately, rather than all as part of the URL, that might help it understand the data more correctly.